# Just looking to see if there's a way of string concatenating a string variable onto an onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this piece of code that gets a list of addresses from a postcode. It does this by using the GET function from an api. when the JSON data is returned I have split it up and I now have a javascript array inside a function to manipulate the DOM to add a dropdown menu that a user can select their address from

I am currently using a dropdown menu that a user can select their address from a list of addresses and an onclick functionality (this is the part that I am having issues with). from which a function should populate other fields (this is not a concern for now). Sorry it's a poor explanattion but there is a lot going on!

```js
    var soil = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var a="";
    
    function findAddress (){
        stuff = document.getElementById("postcode").value;
        soil.open("GET", "https://api.getaddress.io/find/"+stuff+"?api-key=x", false);
        soil.send(null);
        var r = JSON.parse(soil.response);
    
        var x = document.getElementById("address");   // Get the element with id="demo"
        var str="";
        x.innerHTML+="<div class=dropdown> <button onclick=myFunction() class=dropbtn>Dropdown</button>   <div id=myDropdown class=dropdown-content>";
        var y = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
        for (i=0;i<r.addresses.length;i++){
            a=r.addresses[i];
            y.innerHTML+="<a onclick=submitAddress(a)>" + r.addresses[i] + "</a>";
        }
        x.innerHTML+="</div>";
        x.innerHTML+="</div>";
    }
    function submitAddress(a){
        
        var x = document.getElementById("address");   // Get the element with id="demo"
        x.innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("houseNum").value = a;
    }
    
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
<select>
    <option type="submit" value="mr">Mr</option>
    <option type="submit" value="mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option type="submit" value="ms">Ms</option>
    <option type="submit" value="miss">Miss</option>
    <option type="submit" value="dr">Dr</option>
 </select><br><br>
    
    
    <label>First Name<span style="color:red;">*</span>:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" class="payment_firstname" name="firstname" required><br><br><br>
    <label>Surname:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" class="payment_lastname" name="lastname"><br><br><br>
    <label>Email Address<span style="color:red;">*</span>:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" class="payment_email" name="email" required><br><br><br>
    <label>Confirm Email<span style="color:red;">*</span>:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" class="payment_cemail" name="cemail" required><br><br><br>
     <label>Telephone:</label>&nbsp;
     <input type="text" class="payment_telephone" name="Telephone" ><br><br><br>
    <label>House Name/No:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="houseNum" class="payment_telephone" name="houseNum" ><br><br><br>
    <label>County:</label>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="houseCounty" class="payment_telephone" name="houseCounty" ><br><br><br>
    <label>Postcode:</label>&nbsp;
    
    <input type="text" id="postcode" class="payment_postcode" name="Postcode">&nbsp;<button onclick="findAddress()" style="height: 35px;">Find Address</button><br><br>
```

The results I am getting is that the number of the property is being put into the function and not the full indexed string of the array that is    -1 test crescent, test city, test county- and all that is getting fed into the function is the first number

Comment: sorry the innerhtml should read "y.innerHTML+="<a onclick=submitAddress("+r.addresses[i]+")>" + r.addresses[i] + "</a>";"

Comment: There is a demo on the API site, which provides the code and does exactly what you want. Also as that's a paid API, you will want to proxy the request so your api key is not public and your quota is not fair game.

Comment: It would be better if you leave only the part related to your example in code snippet. Also replace API call with prepopulated array, because API call doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got it right, but to build for example select options from an array you could use `map()` function.
Check if user changed address in select you could use `onchange` event instead of `onclick`
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onchange

```js
let addressesArray = [
"67-69 Shelton Street, , , , , London, ",
    "Aace Cleaning group limited, Shelton Street, , , , London, Greater London",
    "Annabelle Grace Events Management, 71-75 Shelton Street, , , , London, Greater London",
    "Apex Base Solutions, 71-75 Shelton Street, , , , London, "
]
let list = addressesArray.map( item => `<option>${item}</option>`);
var select = document.createElement('select');
select.innerHTML = list;
document.body.appendChild(select);
```